# How to adjust x axis labels in a seaborn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot histogram similar to this:[Actual plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd12x.png)

However, I am unable to customize the x axis labels similar to the above figure.
My seaborn plot looks something like this,
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHYkT.png)

I want the same x-axis labels ranging from 0 to 25000 with equal interval of 5000. It would be great if anyone can guide me in the right direction?

Code for my figure:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
kws = dict(linewidth=.3, edgecolor='k')
g = sns.FacetGrid(college, hue='Private',size=6, aspect=2, palette = 'coolwarm')
g = g.map(plt.hist, 'Outstate', bins=24,alpha = 0.7,**kws).add_legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by simply add:

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(start=0, stop=25000, num=6))
```

Comment: Thanks ! That helped.